# Is there way to do partial text stylization in vue (nuxt.js)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, web, nuxt.js

We are creating an application in vue

Does anyone know how to format text partially
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUFhk.png)?

You cannot create hard constraints from ellipses, but this functional may be procedural.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what words you need to style, try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      messages: { unstyled: 'no styling!', styled: 'platformy dobrix del!' },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    words(string) {
      return string.split(/\s+/);
    },
    isMarked(string) {
      return /dobrix/i.test(string);
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.marked {
  color: red;
  position:relative;
}
.marked::before {
  content: "";
  background: turquoise;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 92%;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
*{
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(value, name) in messages" :key="name">
      <span v-for="(word, index) in words(value)" :key="index">
        <span v-if="isMarked(word)" class="marked">{{ word }} </span>
        <span v-else>{{ word }} </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```